# EntityFrameWork in Windows Service

Tags: entity-framework-core, windows-services

I created a Windows Service (.net core 6) (sample service to learn about windows service) and installed EntityFramework core and EF SQLServer. The installation of the windows service is aborted with the following error. I tried installing using InstallUtil directly pointing to the exe in 'Release'. The same service with out any EntityFrameWork packages is installing alright and could see the service in the control panel. But after adding the DBContext with just one model and the packages in the service, the installation fails (tried both 32 bit and 64 bit installutil). What could possibly be breaking?

Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
See the contents of the log file for the

```
C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.InstallLog.
Installing assembly 'C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   assemblypath = C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe
   logfile = C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.InstallLog
An exception occurred while trying to find the installers in the C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe assembly.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Aborting installation for C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe.

An exception occurred during the Install phase.

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get installer types in the C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe assembly.
The inner exception System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was thrown with the following error message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..

The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.InstallLog.
Rolling back assembly 'C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   assemblypath = C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe
   logfile = C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.InstallLog
An exception occurred while trying to find the installers in the C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe assembly.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Aborting installation for C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller installer.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get installer types in the C:\Users\nithyana\source\repos\SampleWindowsService\SampleWindowsService\bin\Release\SampleWindowsService.exe assembly.
The inner exception System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was thrown with the following error message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..

An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation. This exception will be ignored and the rollback will continue. However, the machine might not fully revert to its initial state after the rollback is complete.

The Rollback phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.
The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed.
```

I tried adding Anallyzer package exclusively as the dll was missing in the 'Release' based on the dependencies of the EF package. But the dll didn't show up in the 'Release' and installation still failed.

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved! Create a class library proj with EF packages (depends on .Net version) and reference that in the service.